# Conservation of energy when an object comes to rest

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

Can someone explain conservation of energy to me? Here is what I don't understand: if one particle is moving towards another (say one has a mass much larger than the other, so it is like the Earth and a small object moving towards the Earth), then the particle will be getting faster as it moves closer to the other (kinetic energy increases) and potential energy will decrease. So far so good. But what about when it reaches the particle? Potential energy will be at its minimum here, presumably zero although I've heard that it could be defined to be another value, but speed will also be zero so kinetic energy will be zero. So according to conservation of energy it seems that kinetic energy should be at the maximum value when one particle reaches the other and potential energy should be at its minimum, but what really happens is that they are both at their minimum, although kinetic energy is at its maximum 'just before' it reaches the particle. This seems to me to violate conservation of energy.

Also, at any distance from the more massive particle, one could hold the small particle in place so that it has potential energy but no kinetic energy. So it seems the relationship between potential energy and kinetic energy only holds when particles are allowed to move freely, and conservation of energy is not true in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conservation of energy is always true.

In the first case, the two particles start with some potential energy $U$ far apart and then start moving one against each other. As they get closer and closer, potential energy is transformed into kinetic energy $K$ so that at any time conservation of energy holds

$$U(t)+K(t)=U(t')+K(t')$$ where $t$ and $t'$ are any two times. One instant before colliding, the potential energy is at its *minimum* and the kinetic energy at its *maximum* (in the case of an attractive force like gravity).

Now, the two particles collide! Unfortunately, collisions are violent events where things get tricky. But this does not mean that conservation of energy is violated! Three main possibilities are there and depends mostly on the size and material properties of the particles and on the strength of the collision:

1. the particles bounce back against each other in a perfectly elastic way. Think of a very elastic ball falling down: it will bounce. Conservation of energy holds so that the particles just flip their speed ($K\approx v^2$ so $K$ does not change), the kinetic energy is conserved and can be now used to transform it into potential energy as the particles move *apart*. Still the total energy $U+K$ is conserved.
2. the particles *loose* all of their energy and stop. Think of two cars colliding headfront. Again, this does not mean energy is lost: it just got transformed into heat and elastic deformations due to the collision (the two cars are now broken). Again, energy is conserved but the two particles lost it all, are immobile, and all the energy has flown somewhere else. For conservation of energy to be complete, you need to consider all source of energy (heat, elastic energy, vibrations of the atoms...)
3. mixed cases in which the particles loose some energy but not all of it. Think of a rock falling down: it will bounce back a bit but not as high as an elastic ball. Again, part of the energy goes into heat but the *total* energy is conserved. Or the two particles after the collision move together (think of a cannonball hitting a mosquito).

So you see conservation of energy *always* holds, you just need to figure out where the energy you thought you lost went! Solving collision is very hard without a detailed model of the collision. Usually the main cases (elastic = particle conserve their energy and inelastic = one or both particle(s) loose all of their energy) are considered.

The second question you asked it's simpler: if one of the two particles is immobilizes its kinetic energy $K_i=0$ is zero and its potential energy $U_i$ does not change because the particle does not move. So their sum is constant and conserved. The second particle (moving) starts with only potential energy $U_m(0)$, which over time it converts into kinetic energy $K_m(t)$ so that $K_m(t)+U_m(t)=U_m(0)$ is *constat*. Again, energy is conserved. When the collision happens, the reasoning as before holds: still, energy is conserved. Of course, if whatever is holding the first particle in place is consuming energy (your muscles for examples, or a motor keeping the particle fixed...) that has to be included in your model!

Comment: "Again, this does not mean energy is lost: it just got transformed into heat and elastic deformations" But I thought the total of potential and kinetic energy had to be conserved. Heat is not part of kinetic or potential energy.

Comment: No total energy is conserved! During the collision, you need to take into account the work done by the forces in the collision, heat production and elastic energy of deformations. Not all of this in conservative. What is *always* conserved is the sum of kinetic energy+potential energy (of conservative forces)+work done by non conservative forces+heat (which, microscopically, is sort of another form of kinetic energy). Classical mechanics usually not handles what happens microscopically during collisions. But TOTAL energy is ALWAYS conserved

Comment: Total energy includes internal energy. Physics mechanics sometimes assumes rigid bodies where the internal energy is constant, and here total energy is kinetic plus potential. For non-rigid bodies, total energy includes internal energy and internal energy can change. Internal energy is sometimes incorrectly called "heat"; this is not correct. Heat, like work, is energy transferred.  Heat and/or work into a system can change the internal energy of the system.  See a thermodynamics textbook such as one by Sonntag and Van Wylen.